# Delete a token using Locksmith and Swift 4

Tags: swift, token, keychain

I successfully saved a token using Locksmith, but now I want to delete it when the user logs out.

Here is the code that I tried to use to delete the token, but this did not work:

```
let _ = try? Locksmith.deleteDataForUserAccount(userAccount: "github")
```

The equivalent using KeychainWrapper would look like this:

```
let keychainResult = KeychainWrapper.defaultKeychainWrapper.remove(key: KEY_UID)
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping the `try` call inside a do-try to see if it's yielding an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API that I was using required a call in order to delete the token.